# TinyMCE removes the assigned id attribute value of textarea and assigns a default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, tinymce

In one of my Rails application, I have a form where I have multiple text areas and I have assigned all the text areas with a specific `id` attribute value, but while loading the form, normally the text area would be hidden and I am taking the value using TinyMCE get method (using the attribute `id`). Here my problem is that, when the form is loaded the value of the Id attribute is also changing to some default value. for e.g.,

```
<%= text_area_tag "description",'', :class=>"validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input sub_description", :id=>"sub_question-text", :style=>"width: 426px;  height: 117px; border: 1px solid rgb(209, 209, 209); float:left;" %>
```

The above text_area which I have specified has the `Id` value `sub_question-text`, but when the form is loaded, it changes to,

```
<textarea class="validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input sub_description" id="mce_33" name="description" style="width: 426px; height: 117px; border: 1px solid rgb(209, 209, 209); float: left; display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
```

Now, the `id` attribute has the value `mce_33`.

I have the following init method for tinyMCE.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        editor_selector : "sub_description",
        width:"350",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,hr,removeformat,|,sub,sup,charmap,|,ltr,rtl",
        //theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        //theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/example.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",


    });
```

I don't know what the issue is. Please help.

Comment: TinyMCE experts, please help

Comment: what version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: TinyMCE 3.4.5 with Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.3. TinyMCE is used as a plugin in my app.

Comment: hmm, i am sorry, but i got no idea

Comment: The form in which I am getting this issue is being loaded remotely. Can that be an issue?

Comment: that depends. unfortunatly i am not familiar with ruby at all.